# Really Is not possible to delete User or any other option.?

Tags: community, user-record, user-registration

I have created a community where any public user can self register.

As a developer, I'm developing a different functionality for Self registration Page.

Now I've to test self Registration functionality. Salesforce not allow to create a user with duplicate email. and we are not able to delete the user. So here How can i fully test this functionality.

I have already created 15-20 User until with different email.Now how can I move forward to test this?

Comment: To create a User, User Name needs to be unique not Email. So you can create multiple users with same email but different User Names.

Comment: @AjayPrakashDubey Even I deactivate it does not allow me to create user with same email. In my code I've setup the username of customer is email.

Comment: @Venky I've setup the username of customer is email

Comment: then you need to make Email of customer unique field.

Answer (score 0):

Create user inside test class and check for functionality

```
 @isTest
private class YourTestClass {

      private static Integer genRandomNumber() {
        return Crypto.getRandomInteger();
      }
      private  User genPersonAccountUser() {
            User testUser = new User();
            testUser.Username = 'Name+' + genRandomNumber() + '@example.com';
            testUser.Lastname = 'LastName';
            testUser.Firstname = 'FirstName';
            testUser.Alias = ('ABCD' + genRandomNumber()).left(8);
            testUser.email = 'Name+' + genRandomNumber() + '@example.com';
            insert testUser;
            return testUser;
      }
     @isTest(SeeAllData=False)
     private static void testForUser() {
         List<user> users=new List<user>();
         for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
           users.add(genPersonAccountUser);
          //Test Functionality using users 
      }       
}
```

In Org you can create user with same **Email** address but not Same **username**

Comment: In my test class also I'm not able to create a community user. "userId = Site.createExternalUser(u, accountId, putPassowrd);" This part is not creating user.

Comment: To allow an external user to access your community, add them to an account as a contact record and then enable the contact record as a customer user or partner user, depending on your business relationship.

Comment: In test Case also you have to create contact and account to an user , then try to create External user